# dependsOn another task with a parameter value

Tags: gradle

I have a task from a plugin which I call on command line like this:

```
$ gradle myTask -PsomeArg=<value>
```

I want to define another task that would do exactly the same with a default parameter value. I expect to be able to call it like this:

```
$ gradle otherTask
```

I assume my task should look something like this:

```
task otherTask (dependsOn: 'myTask', someArg: 'value') {...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a task that would set default value for project property `someArg` when this value is not provided as command line parameter :

```
task otherTask (){
    finalizedBy myTask
    doFirst{
        if (!project.hasProperty("someArg")) {
            project.ext.set("someArg", "defaultValue")
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you need to use `finalizedBy` dependency type here: if you use `otherTask.dependsOn myTask` the task `myTask` will be executed first (so default value for property `someArg` will not be set yet)

Execution result:

```
./gradlew myTask -PsomeArg=myValue
  > Task :myTask
    executing task pluginTask with arg: myValue

./gradlew otherTask -PsomeArg=myValue
  > Task :myTask
    executing task pluginTask with arg: myValue

./gradlew otherTask
  > Task :myTask
    executing task pluginTask with arg: defaultValue
```